# Active backup or restore

Tags: sql-server

Hoje ao fazer um insert em uma tabela foi apresentada a mensagem: The transaction log for database “nome do banco” is full due to “ACTIVE BACKUP OR RESTORE”.
Qual o motivo dessa mensagem?

Answer (score 0):

Por padrão, no SQL Server, todo banco de dados possui um arquivo com extensão .ldf que armazena os logs de transações. Dependendo das configurações ele pode chegar ao seu tamanho limite e começar a apresentar a mensagem que você recebeu.

Uma das formas de contornar esta situação é definir uma estratégia de autocrescimento (autogrowth) de acordo com o espaço disponível no hd. Para isto, no Management Studio, basta clicar com o botão direito do mouse sobre o banco e selecionar a opção Propriedades. No menu do lado esquerdo escolha a opção Files (Arquivos) e localize o arquivo de LOG do seu banco. Na coluna Autogrowth/Maxsize você define sua estratégia.

Se não quiser/puder mexer nestas configurações você pode executar o comando shrink de acordo com o artigo abaixo:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3311/how-to-shrink-the-transaction-log/

Em ambos os casos vai precisar ficar sempre de olho no espaço que o arquivo está ocupando.